# How to remove '\n' from base64 respond of Github APIs?

Tags: github, utf-8, base64, github-api

I am trying to make an android application with multiline textview which will use Github APIs to fetch contents. But github responds with base64 encoding. Example of one of such respond is :

> cGFja2FnZSBTZWFyY2hpbmc7CgovKioKICogQ3JlYXRlZCBieSBuaWt1bmog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\naWFsX1NlYXJjaChhLDU2KSk7CiAgICB9Cn0K\n

Now whenever I have tried to decode this , error occurs due to presence of "\n" in between . I have tried many methods to remove \n but did not worked out.Some of those are :

- s = s.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "");
- s = s.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", " ");
- s = s.replace("\n","");

After decoding these code , output is :

[image]

Please help me to decode Github encoded content.

Comment: You can return the raw contents using the [media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) raw if you'd rather not parse the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `\n` of your text you can use the next regex:

```
(\\n)
```

`()` : say you to match all what contains exactly inside.

`\\` : coincidence with character \

`n` : coincidence with character n

Example in regex: [Link Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3iTYxj/2)